# Convergence test of a series? $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\pi)^n}{2^{2n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the best way to test the convergence of the following series? My first guess is to use the Leibniz rule, but the exercise also asks to calculate it's sum, that makes me think that this is a geometric series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-\pi)^n}{2^{2n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-\pi)^n}{2^{2n+1}} =\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac\pi4\right)^n$$ which is an infinite Geometric Series with common ratio  $\displaystyle r=-\dfrac\pi4$ here $|r|<1$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{-\pi^{n}}{2^{2n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \left(\frac{-\pi}{4}\right)^{n}$$

So you are correct in assuming it's a geometric series with first term $\frac{1}{2}$ and common ratio $\frac{-\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-\pi)^n}{2^{2n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(\frac{-\pi}{4}\big)^n$$

Can you conclude now?